# Formatting MySQL query with timestamp & count

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, count

I have a mysql table like :

```
article   smallint(5)     (id of a specific article)
date      varchar(14)       (timestamp)
ip        varchar(15)       (ip visiting the article)
```

I would like to create two arrays :

- one with all the unique date in the format DD-MM-YY
- one with the number of visits on each date

So, i need to select the unique timestamp by day and i think it is possible with :

```
SELECT date 
FROM visites 
WHERE article = '$id' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date), '%a %d %b')
```

After using

```
strftime('%a %d %b', $tab['date'])
```

, seems good.

But i don't know how to count the unique ip for each day, in order to plot the number of visits everyday on an article.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: You can give a try to: `SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) ...`

Comment: Sldo, youi shouldn't be storing dates in a varchar. Use the timestamp or date column type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date , COUNT (IP)
FROM visites 
WHERE article = '$id' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date), '%a %d %b')
```

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect!